# How to write JavaScript code that allows for defaults to be overrided

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I would like to use this [text-highlighting library](https://github.com/Perlego/texthighlighter#simple-example) in my Vue project. Here's an example from their website of how it can be used:

```js
import TextHighlighter from '@perlego/text-highlighter';
import { isDuplicate } from './utils'; 
import highlightsApi from './services/highlights-api';

class ArticleView {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    const pageElement = document.getElementById("article");
    this.highlighter = new TextHighlighter(
      pageElement, 
      {
        version: "independencia",
        onBeforeHighlight: this.onBeforeHighlight,
        onAfterHighlight: this.onAfterHighlight,
        preprocessDescriptors: this.preprocessDescriptors,
        onRemoveHighlight: this.onRemoveHighlight
    });
  }

  onBeforeHighlight = (range) => {
    return !isDuplicate(range)
  }

  onRemoveHighlight = (highlightElement) => {
    const proceed = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this highlight?");
    return proceed;
  }

  preprocessDescriptors = (range, descriptors, timestamp) => {
    // Add an ID to the class list to identify each highlight 
    // (A highlight can be represented by a group of elements in the DOM).
    const uniqueId = `hlt-${Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(2, 15) +
      Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(2, 15)}`;

    const descriptorsWithIds = descriptors.map(descriptor => {
      const [wrapper, ...rest] = descriptor;
      return [
        wrapper.replace(
          'class="highlighted"',
          `class="highlighted ${uniqueId}"`
        ),
        ...rest
      ];
    });

    return { descriptors: descriptorsWithIds, meta: { id: uniqueId } };
  }

  onAfterHighlight = (range, descriptors, timestamp, meta) => {
    highlightsApi.saveBatch(meta.id, descriptorsWithIds)
      .then((result) => {
        // Do something with the highlights that have been saved.
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  render = () => {
    // Code that takes the data for the article and adds it to the DOM
    // based on a html template here.
  }
}
```

Using the above example, I would like to setup the highlighter (similar to the above code, but in a different file, for example `./utils/highlighter.js`) with all the default options I want (`onBeforeHighlight`, `onRemoveHighlight`, etc.), and then be able to import it from there and override the options for which I don't want to use the defaults, so it looks something like this in the importing file:

```js
import highlighter from "../utils/highlighter.js";

const overridingOptions = {
  onAfterHighlight: (range, descriptors, timestamp, meta) => {
    console.log(range, descriptors, timestamp, meta);
  }
};

const target = document.getElementsByClassName("testme")[0];
highlighter(target, overridingOptions);
```

For some reason, I am not able to understand how to modify the `ArticleView` example to fit my needs, so I think I need to see this done once. How should the code in `./utils/highlighter.js` look to make this possible?

Comment: Do you even want to call your `highlighter` with `new`?

Comment: Just make it accept a second parameter, and use `Object.assign(defaultsOptions, overridingOptions)`

Comment: @Bergi I don't mind calling `highlighter` with `new` or not. Is the code very different in both those situations? For overriding options, I was thinking of something like `updatedOptions = { ...defaultOptions, ...overrideOptions }`

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Just try it!

Comment: @Bergi it's the rest of the class that I'm not sure how to write.

Comment: Then don't make it a `class` - make it a normal function that returns the highlighter.